# Use Angular Pipe within shorthand if statement

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I use a custom pipe within a shorthand if statement??

This is the code I am trying to use

`<h1>Total Value {{data ? totalValue | moneyFormat : '$0'}}`

and this is the error I am getting

```
Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Conditional expression data ? totalValue | moneyFormat : null requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression
```

So basically I have set up a pipe that formats money, this is my pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'moneyFormat'})
export class MoneyFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number) {
        const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
          style: 'currency',
          currency: 'USD'
        });
        let formattedValue = formatter.format(value);
        formattedValue = formattedValue.slice(0, -3);
        return formattedValue;
    }
}
```

Now I know this works since I have used this else where in scenarios like

`<p>This is your dollar amount {{dollarAmount | formatMoney}}`

Am I missing something? Am I doing this wrong?

Keep in mind what I have done is an example for simplicity sake and not the true functionality of the conditional statement. I am fully aware I could return $0 using the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to wrap some part in parenthesis:

```
{{data ? (totalValue | moneyFormat) : '$0'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a more explicit format for what it should do:

```
{{(data ? totalValue : '$0') | moneyFormat }}
```

which should evaluate roughly to :

```
if (data) {totalValue | moneyFormat;} else { '$0' | moneyFormat }
```

Comment: Yeah the issue is that the else value may not be a number in most cases